# Simple rectifier, solar to 18v ac

Tags: inverter, rectifier, h-bridge, solar-energy

Would it be possible to charge a Ring video door bell from solar power, but using the doorbells external pins for the wiring of a 8 to 24v ac transformer. Say using a 12v solar panel, would regulation be necessary or can a simple circuit handle the swing in voltage from the panel? Would a simple circuit be economically comparable to a H-bridge as a possible prebuilt solution? What would an example of such a circuit look like?

Comment: Would it be possible to make a solar system which powers the Ring gadget?  Yes.  Would it be easy?  It depends on what you can find out about the product's power supply, for example does it really need AC, or does it just tolerate it because it's meant to be powered from a bell transformer?   If it needs AC would it be okay with a square wave?   Likely there are better solutions for achieving a solar powered camera system.

Comment: The manufacturer states the 6-24v pins are for use without a chime, which requires the use of the some of the same pins, and for ac current only. The only other option is charging using the the built in usb port. This can be done through solar or through the use of an ac wall adapter to convert it into 5v dc. I can use a 5v dc solar system but this has proven to be inefficient on this specific device. I would like to test the efficiency of charging using the transformer inputs with something fairly simple and efficient.

Comment: There is no "simple" way to emulate a bell transformer's output from a solar cell.  It can be done, but not simply, especially when you don't have a real specification for what is required, eg, can you use a square wave or must you really approximate a sine?  It's not even clear that the AC requirement is real.  Anyway the question is off topic.